# ftp - connection refused on Mac

Tags: macos, ftp, localhost

If I run `ftp localhost` on Mac terminal, it shows the following result.

```
Trying ::1...
ftp: Can't connect to `::1': Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
ftp: Can't connect to `127.0.0.1': Connection refused
ftp: Can't connect to `localhost'
```

I already have apache installed on Mac, and I checked that out by entering `localhost` on the browser.

How do you diagnose this matter, and what should I take for the next step?

PS some people might ask me about the firewall. I checked that out as well in the system preferences and it's off.

Comment: Apache is not an FTP server.

Comment: @duskwuff Right.. that was irrelevant. Anyways, I tried to connect to localhost with FileZilla, but I keep failing to connect. I went to the network configuration wizard, and it says that the connection to the server got closed prematurely. So far I had absolutely no problem connecting to the other external hosts via FileZilla, and the localhost is the only one that I cannot connect to.

Comment: What makes you think you're running an FTP server? There is no FTP server installed nor active by default on Mac OS X.